# With or without the indefinite article (an)?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Which usage is correct? with or without the indefinite article (an)?

1. The study revealed inadequacy in understanding this difficult part of the problem.

or

2. The study revealed (an) inadequacy in understanding this difficult part of the problem.

Comment: _The study revealed inadequacy in **the** understanding **of** this difficult part of the problem._

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and mean slightly different things.

> "revealed inadequacy" means there was broad inadequacy in understanding, perhaps in multiple areas.
>
> "revealed an inadequacy" means there is at least one specific area of inadequacy.

Comment: It seems that your answer is not quite right. **Inadequacy** is largely an uncountable noun. If countable, it is generally used in the plural :  _The inadequacies of the current system have already been recognised._

Comment: It seems that your comment merely justifies my answer.  "Broad inadequacy, perhaps in multiple areas," indicates something that is uncountable.

Comment: I ment the usage of the indefinite article. Compare [this1](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&dcr=0&ei=nK8mWpLeCqLB6QS8iIeoDQ&q=%22revealed+the+inadequacy+of%22&oq=%22revealed+the+inadequacy+of%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...7181.13508.0.15778.8.8.0.0.0.0.90.529.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.8KtEffXJlpw) and [this2](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&dcr=0&ei=W68mWqyFD8aB6ATigbvwAQ&q=%22revealed+an+inadequacy+of%22&oq=%22revealed+an+inadequacy+of%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...85656.87243.0.89451.3.3.0.0.0.0.76.192.3.3.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.bM041Eiivq8) - 360000:2500

Comment: The indefinite article would indicate the inadequacy is not uncountable and that one exists.